# Parsing out a string that is surrounded by quotes and has the word "... " in it and print the string Python Regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use REGEX to parse out a string the first text by quotes and has the word "quoted" in it
. Finally I print out the string.
The output should be "This is a quoted message"

```
import re
text = 'I have "message with quotes" in it. "This is a quoted message."'
r = re.search('".*?quoted.*?"', text) #wrong
if r == None:
    print("not found")
else:
    print(text[r.regs[0][0]:r.regs[0][1]]) #print out the string
```

Comment: The edit history of this question is quite bizarre - it seems that, after you got your answer, you then decided to replace the question with gibberish, and you did this several times -- and resulted in it being deleted by the moderators for a period of time. It is quite disrespectful to M Z and to me, who have taken the trouble to answer your question for you. Please do not do that again.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that an online editor like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) could really come in handy here.

Second, here's a working regex string:

```py
'"[^"]*quoted[^"]*"'
```

Let me explain what's going on:

When you used `'".*?quoted.*?"'` and got `"message with quotes" in it. "This is a quoted message."`, what was happening was the `.*` also matched quotation marks `"`. Even though the quantifier was set to lazy, regex is reading from left to right, which means it will start expanding from the left to the right. Now in this case, I've replaced `.` with `[^"]`, which just means that all quotation marks will be avoided, so now, `[^"]*` cannot match with `"`, and the expected string is produced.

Comment: Just to draw your attention to the fact that the question is now restored, after being deleted for a period of time earlier -- see also the comment that I have now posted under the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp is nearly correct.  There are two things you need:

- Use parentheses to capture the bit that you are interested in keeping - this can then be used with the `group` method. The `"` characters are not included in the capture group. (I am assuming here that where you use them in the question, it is only to quote the string and not to imply that you want them as part of the output.)
- Your first `.*?` will match any amount of any (non-newline) character, and even though it is "lazy" rather than greedy, it will still find the match with the first available starting position, which may cause it to include `"` characters themselves. It should be replaced by `[^"]*?` to ensure that these are not matched. (The second `.*?` can be changed similarly or left as-is; it shouldn't matter, as in that case the lazy quantifier is enough to ensure that it doesn't match any `"` characters.)

```
import re
text = 'I have "message with quotes" in it. "This is a quoted message."'
r = re.search('"([^"]*?quoted.*?)"', text)
if r == None:
    print("not found")
else:
    print(r.group(1))
```

This gives:

```
This is a quoted message.
```

Comment: You have to think in terms of whether the whole pattern will match or not. The point is that if it tries a starting position at the first `"`, then it will find that it can't make it match because the `[^"]` bit is not allowed to match the second `"` that is between there and the word `quoted`, so the whole thing doesn't match. So then it keeps trying later starting positions (that's what `search` does) until it gets to a later `"` as starting position and this time it does match.

Comment: Not specifically, I'm afraid - just practice.

Comment: @keepitrealman Hopefully you've also noticed that here I have still used a lazy quantifier `[^"]*?` while M Z has changed it to a greedy quantifier `[^"]*`, and that they *both work*. The two regexp would work in slightly different ways if the string contained the word "quoted" more than once (as you could discover if you experiment with additional capture groups), but the overall effect would still be the same.